# How can I create sheet 2 in a CSV file by using Python code?

Tags: python, csv

Is there is way to create sheet 2 in same csv file by using python code

Comment: Nope. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29615196/is-csv-with-multi-tabs-sheet-possible

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please review [**How to ask**](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) questions on Stack Overflow and [what types of questions can be asked](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [what types should be avoided](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask)

Comment: You need to expand your question. What data do you have (show examples) and what kind of output are you trying to achieve with it?

Comment: I have a dictionary like {'First':1,'Second':2}.if i save this dictionary to **my_file.csv** by using DictWriter,my result will be stored in my_file.csv's **sheet 2** not in **sheet 1**.That is my question.Is possible to make this?

Comment: Did you get the answer for this @Ashok?

Answer (score 1):

yes. There is :

```
df = pd.read_excel("C:\\DWDM\\Status.xlsx") # read ur original file

workbook = load_workbook(filename="C:\\DWDM\\Status.xlsx")

ws2 = workbook.create_sheet("Summary", 0) # other sheet with name Summary is added to the same.
```

and you can check the same with "workbook.sheetnames"

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by using multiple CSV files - one CSV file per sheet.

A comma-separated value file is a plain text format. It is only going to be able to represent flat data, such as a table (or a "sheet")

When storing multiple sheets, you should use separate CSV files. You can write each one separately and import/parse them individually into their destination.

Comment: Can you give me a example?