# Add multiple csv in a single csv sheet in tabs using Pandas

Tags: python, excel, python-3.x, pandas, csv

I have multiple csv files, lets say a.csv , b.csv . I want  both a.csv and b.csv in a new c.csv . Both new csv should be in tabs inside as it is. I just want to add both csv in tabs . Is there any short way doing that in pandas. I have the below code with me but its not giving any output ,however its executing . Tried checking few posts in stackoverflow but somehow I did not got the wanted output. Please help me with some better solution.

```
folders=next(os.walk('.'))[1]
for host in folders:
    Path=os.path.join(os.getcwd(),host)                    
    all_files = glob.glob(os.path.join(Path, "*.csv"))     
    df_from_each_file = (pd.read_csv(f) for f in all_files)
    df   = pd.concat(df_from_each_file, ignore_index=True)
    df.to_csv('c.csv,' index=False)
```

Comment: " Both new csv should be in tabs inside as it is". what do you mean by this?? like two different sheets in a CSV?

Comment: Its like , We want to add two existing csv into a new csv in tabs.

Comment: Hope this URL helps you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29615196/is-csv-with-multi-tabs-sheet-possible

Comment: It is useful but did not figured out from it. Looking for pandas solutions.

Comment: Are you looking for a ‘tab’ as in what you get in an Excel workbook? If so, you cannot do that with a CSV.

Comment: Can it be done - output as excel having both tha csv in tab, if possible convert input csv in excel at start of code only ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A CSV file is really only ever a single sheet. An Excel `xlsx` file though does support sheets. Pandas can be made to write directly to an Excel file using an `ExcelWriter`. Something like the following should do what you need:

```
import pandas as pd
import xlsxwriter
import glob
import os

writer = pd.ExcelWriter('multi_sheet.xlsx', engine='xlsxwriter')
folders = next(os.walk('.'))[1]

for host in folders:
    Path = os.path.join(os.getcwd(), host)

    for f in glob.glob(os.path.join(Path, "*.csv")):
        print(f)
        df = pd.read_csv(f)
        df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name=os.path.basename(f)[:31])

writer.save()
```

For every CSV file that is found in your folders, a new Excel sheet will be created. The name of the sheet is the name of the CSV file, e.g. `a.csv` would have the sheetname `a`.

Note: Excel has a restriction of 31 characters for a sheet name.

Comment: Is it going to have two tabs in excel for the 2 cvs? I think it will have only one ?sorry for asking this  I am outside I can only test after sometime .

Comment: You will get one sheet per CSV file.

Comment: Any way to have name more than 31 characters of sheet ?

Comment: That appears to be a restriction in Excel. If you have filenames which are longer, you would at least need to use `[:31]` instead. I have updated the script.