# How to write the data into multiple sheets using csv writer

Tags: c#, excel, export-to-csv

Here is a example of writing data to csv file, passing mycustomTypeList and write records.

var csv = new CsvWriter( stream );
csv.WriteRecords( myCustomTypeList );

Suppose I have two tables and want to write data seperately in csv file like sheet 1 and sheet 2, how can i write using csvwriter ? is it possible ?

Comment: Csv does not have native support for sheets.

Comment: please have a look to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29615196/is-csv-with-multi-tabs-sheet-possible

Comment: How about writing multiple csv, one for each table?

Comment: Writing multiple csv worked fine.