# How to spool data in multiple sheets in a same csv file using sqlplus

Tags: sql, oracle, sqlplus

I need to run multiple queries in a oracle database and to spool then in a same CSV file with multiple tabs. Could you please help me in achieving it.

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/643137/how-do-i-spool-to-a-csv-formatted-file-using-sqlplus

Comment: Does "CSV file with multiple tabs" really mean an Excel file with multiple sheets?

Comment: Yes Alex, the requirement is to have multiple sheets in an excel file. By spooling them with SQLPLUS connection.

Comment: @Abra  - No that is about generating only one set of SQL result into a CSV file. I have requirement to run , Multiple SQLs  by establishing SQLPLUS connection and spool all reports in a single CSV file

Comment: Note : There are possibilities , that few tabs can exceed more than 1 million sometimes

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29615196/is-csv-with-multi-tabs-sheet-possible/29616152

Comment: @Abra no it was with some other details.