# how to create a new sheet in existing csv file using python and add some data into that

Tags: python

i want to add a new sheet in existing CSV file with sheet name "summary" and write some data into the newly created sheet using python.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CSV is an acronym for "Comma Separated Values". It is not a table of any type, it's just what its name tells: multiple values, separated by commas. Excel and other table-processing utils has an ability to interpret this values as a table. And, since Excel keeps its tables organised as sheets, it will display your CSV as a table sheet. However CSV has no info about sheets at all. Sheets are not part of the CSV format. Related question can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29615196/is-csv-with-multi-tabs-sheet-possible).

As a possible solution, you may create a separate CSV for each sheet you'd like to use. That is not exactly what you want, but is similar to it.

Answer (score 0):

CSV files don't have sheets. Maybe use you could use Excel instead if you really want multiple sheets, however in my opinion multiple CSV files are a more straightforward alternative.